# Using xskak to move a piece in a non-chess game

Tags: chess, xskak

I'm trying to use `xskak` and `chessboard` to display another game than chess, however I can't get `xskak` to move a piece.

The problem might be that my board is `5x5` instead of `8x8`.

Here's my non-working source, which tries to move the white pawn at c1 to c2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}

\def\neutrinoChar{\bullet}

\makeatletter
\cbDefineNewPiece{white}{X}{
    \raisebox{\depth}{\cfss@whitepiececolor$\neutrinoChar$}
}{
    \BlackEmptySquare\makebox[0pt][r]{\cfss@whitepiececolor\raisebox{\depth}{\makebox[1em]{$\neutrinoChar$}}}
}
\makeatother

\styleB
\setchessboard{
    maxfield=e5
}

\xskakset{defaultfen=ppppp/5/2X2/5/PPPPP}

\newchessgame

\chessboard

\mainline{1. Pc2}
\chessboard[setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]

\end{document}
```

---

I don't actually care about the chess move notation, so some syntax like `c1-c2` would be fine for me.

Comment: Given a 5x5 board and (presumably) non-chess pieces, it would probably be easier to start from scratch than try to get an existing package to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned somewhere in the documentation skak (the engine used internally to execute the moves) doesn't like unusual boards. So instead of `maxfield` you should better use a normal sized board and then restrict the printarea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}

\def\neutrinoChar{\bullet}

\makeatletter
\cbDefineNewPiece{white}{X}{
    \raisebox{\depth}{\cfss@whitepiececolor$\neutrinoChar$}
}{
    \BlackEmptySquare\makebox[0pt][r]{\cfss@whitepiececolor\raisebox{\depth}{\makebox[1em]{$\neutrinoChar$}}}
}
\makeatother

\styleB
\setchessboard{
  printarea=a1-e5
    %maxfield=e5
}

\xskakset{defaultfen=5/5/5/ppppp/5/2X2/5/PPPPP/5}

\newchessgame

\chessboard

\mainline{1. c2}
\chessboard

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know if and how your neutrinoChar is meant to move, but you should be aware that skak will probably not be able to do it. Also skak does some checking if a move is "legal" so not every move you try is executed. (Perhaps some day in the future I will find the time to finish `xchess` ...). But you naturally always can fake moves by changing the position on the board with chessboard keys.

Comment: If I can't make illegal chess moves with `xskak`, then I don't think I can use it for my purpose.

Comment: It depend how "illegal" the moves are. `xchess` that I already mention  allows illegal moves, but it is missing code for printing the moves.

Comment: I don't need to print moves, but I would like to move a pawn backwards and also move the custom piece (neutrino). If this is possible with `xchess` could you give me an example of using `xchess`?

Comment: Moving backward should work but you would have to enter the moves as c3-c2, there is no code for special char moves, but if you don't need the other pieces you could highjack one of them. But I have absolutly not the time now to create some examples (xchess exists only on my PC, it is not online). But if you  only want to update boards you could  simply do something like `clearfield=c2,addpieces=Pc1`.